# Правильное импортирование модулей из SciPy

Tags: python, python-import

Как правильно импортировать модули из библиотеки SciPy?
Допустим необходим модуль io.

1) Импортирование всей библиотеки SciPy:

```
import scipy
```

2)Импортирование через from import:

```
from scipy import io
```

3)Импортирование самого модуля  io:

```
import io
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scipy.io` и `io` это разные независимые модули.

`import scipy` НЕ делает доступными все вложенные модули. Если вы хотите использовать `scipy.io` модуль, то вам его необходимо явно проимпортировать:

```
import scipy.io
```

То что вы спутали его с `io` модулем из стандартной библиотеки является наглядным доводом почему `from scipy import io` следует избегать и оставить этот модуль в пространстве имён `scipy`.

Подытоживая: все три альтернативы в вопросе не точны—используйте `import scipy.io`.

Answer (score 3):

Вариант номер 3 не верный, так как модуль `io` будет стандартный, а не из библиотеки `scipy`.

Импортировать можно так, как вам угодно, лишь бы у вас не было пересечения имен.

Большинство модулей `scipy` имеют специфичные названия, поэтому их можно импортировать напрямую не заботясь о том что они могут пересекаться с другими модулями и перменными.

Главное не импортировать все из библиотеки при помощи `*`, так как вы засорите всю область видимости.